# Apply a limit of 10 after taking distinct records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

In a MySQL table, I would like to take 10 records with **DISTINCT** values.

I am using Zend Framework.

```
$select = $this->getAdapter()->select()
                    ->from('table', 'column')->group('column')
                    ->limit(10, 0);
```

This is the query generated by the above code.

> SELECT table.column FROM
>   table GROUP BY column LIMIT 10

What happens here is that MySQL is taking 10 records first and then applying the group by. So finally, I am getting only 7 records.

How to apply **DISTINCT** first and then take 10 records from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test that SQL against a table -- MySQL applies the `limit` last, so doesn't do what you're saying.  eg test against

```
a0 a1
 1  1
 2  1
 3  2
 4  2
```

and do `select A.a1 from A group by a1 limit 2`.  You should see 1, 2, not 1, 1.
[I wanted to say this as a 'comment' rather than an 'answer', but couldn't]

Comment: yup you are right. actually I passed the results to another query. that's where it got filtered to 7 records. In the original query I got 10 distinct values only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do.

But if i am reading it correct you need 10 records with a certain criteria and then apply the group. not the other way around.

Can't you use WHERE in this case?

> SELECT table.column FROM table **WHERE "*criteria*"** GROUP BY column LIMIT 10

Regards
Mike

Answer (score 0):

This may help you (I didn't test it but so I'm not sure it's working)

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table LIMIT 10
```

If it's not working, you may use a temporary table (like `(SELECT column FROM table) TEMP`), which will select the distinct elements, then a query which will select the first ten results into this table.

Hope this'll help :)

Answer (score 0):

In ZF, You should use *distinct()* method into Your query chain :

```
$select = $this->getAdapter()->select()
                    ->distinct()
                    ->from('table', 'column')
                    ->limit(10, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column
FROM table 
LIMIT 10
GROUP BY column
```

Not sure how to get it into classes though...